# How do I join two lines in vi?

Tags: vim, vi

I have two lines in a text file like below:

```
S<Switch_ID>_F<File type>
_ID<ID number>_T<date+time>_O<Original File name>.DAT
```

I want to append the two lines in vi like below:

```
S<Switch_ID>_F<File type>_ID<ID number>_T<date+time>_O<Original File name>.DAT
```

The second line got deleted and the contents of the second line was appended to the first line.

How could I do it using command mode in vi?

Comment: Unrelated question: why do we require to join two lines?

Comment: @RishabhBhatnagar, coz we need them to be joined.

Comment: Since J is a very easily reachable key, join must be one of the most frequently used operations.
I just wanted to know the use-cases where joins are needed.

Comment: After extensively using vim, I've realised why I'd use join.
It is very much used while coding to merge comment lines or param list or cases when you want to merge expressions like 
```err = someFunction();
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```
into
```if err := someFunction(); err != nil {
    return err
}```

Answer (score 341, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> removes the line change character from the current line, so by pressing "J" at any place in the line you can combine the current line and the next line in the way you want.

Comment: "removes the line change character from the current line" is a pretty awkward way to describe what J does, and is also not really correct. J "joins" this line to the next. In the process it removes the newline, but also manipulates whitespace in other ways.

Answer (score 64):

Vi or Vim?

Anyway, the following command works for Vim in 'nocompatible' mode. That is, I suppose, almost pure vi.

```
:join!
```

If you want to do it from normal command use

```
gJ
```

With 'gJ' you join lines as is -- without adding or removing whitespaces:

```
S<Switch_ID>_F<File type>
_ID<ID number>_T<date+time>_O<Original File name>.DAT
```

Result:

```
S<Switch_ID>_F<File type>_ID<ID number>_T<date+time>_O<Original File name>.DAT
```

With 'J' command you will have:

```
S<Switch_ID>_F<File type> _ID<ID number>_T<date+time>_O<Original File name>.DAT
```

Note space between `type>` and `_ID`.

Comment: Just want to point out that `g/pattern/join` works in VIM while `g/pattern/J` does not. Might help some future people.

Comment: I like your join with pattern, however, it joins two lines with white space. Anyway to join two lines with a pattern without white space?

Comment: g/pattern/join! seems to do that.

Comment: If the next line has spaces at the beginning of the line, `gJ` also keeps those spaces whereas `J` seems to only place a single space character regardless of how many spaces there were at the beginning of the next line

Answer (score 26):

This should do it:

`J`

Comment: 'J' gives extra space while joining lines.

Comment: @MaximKim: And [this is why](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing). Note that `:h J` will tell you how to disable that feature.

Comment: Use `gJ` if you don't want vim to add a space when joining the lines

Answer (score 23):

In vi, `J` (that's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>) or `:join` should do what you want, for the most part. **Note that they adjust whitespace.** In particular, you'll end up with a space between the two joined lines in many cases, and if the second line is indented that indentation will be removed prior to joining.

In Vim you can also use `gJ` (<kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>) or `:join!`. These will join lines without doing any whitespace adjustments.

In Vim, see `:help J` for more information.

Comment: One caveat when using `gJ` and `J` is that both chang the cursor to the joining point, but `:join!` and `:join` dont.

Answer (score 5):

Just replace the "`\n`" with "".

In vi/Vim for every line in the document:

```
%s/>\n_/>_/g
```

If you want to confirm every replacement:

```
%s/>\n_/>_/gc
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to join the selected lines (you are in visual mode), then just press `gJ` to join your lines with no spaces whatsoever.

This is described in greater detail on [the vi/Vim Stack Exchange site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/440/9850).

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> ("$") on the first line, then  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> ("J").

And if you want help, go into vi, and then press <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: $ moves to the end of the row, but it is not necessary for J

Comment: You don't have to be at the end of the line for J to join lines.

Comment: Pressing $ isn't necessary, actually.

Comment: @laurence .pressing $ ensures that the cursor is placed just beside the new line charter and this is a must.

Comment: @Vijay: It is not a must (at least not with Vim 8.1.2269). You get an extra space either way. (Does the configuration of vi/Vim play a role?) [Using `gJ` avoids the extra space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912905/how-do-i-join-two-lines-in-vi/1912925#1912925). What did you try it on?

Comment: `Shift + 4` *only* works on the US keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

In Vim you can also use `gJ`.

ََ

Answer (score 1):

Another way of joining two lines without placing cursor to that line is:

```
:6,6s#\n##
```

Here 6 is the line number to which another line will be join. To display the line number, use `:set nu`.

If we are on the cursor where the next line should be joined, then:

```
:s#\n##
```

In both cases we don't need `g` like `:s#\n##g`, because on one line only one `\n` exist.

Comment: It's easier to use `Shift+V` to select all lines that are to be joined, except the last, and then `:'<,'>s/\n/, /` in this example joining lines while putting a comma and a space at the end of each. Note that when something is selected and we type `:` in normal mode, then the `'<,'>` appears on the command line automatically.

Comment: Good for selected multiple line join with preferred delimiter. Found one typo ... in normal mode or in visual mode?