# How can I delete a new line in Vim?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I join two lines in vi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912905/how-do-i-join-two-lines-in-vi)

I have the following text:

```
the bunny
  is very cute
```

How can I quickly delete the `\n\t` between `bunny` and `is`?

Comment: Link provided by @AndrewMarshall should be applicable here.

Comment: Voted off topic. Using a text editor interactively is not programming. There is `:help`, and lots of web resources for Vim. RTFM.

Comment: @Kaz With all due respect, there are other questions about Vim here and there is even a decently popular `vim` tag.

Comment: @Kaz: It has [been decided that Vim questions belong on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su) (this is an exception to the usual "programming related" requirement).

Comment: @Kaz Definitely not off topic. The FAQ states questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are valid, and the meta question Greg referenced validates it with Vim specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type <kbd>J</kbd> (capital J) to join lines.

Comment: @JonathanLingle: To join without space, use `Jx`.